# What does the String... Groovy Notation stands for?

Tags: java, groovy

What does the **String...** of the following function means?

```
public UpdateSettingsRequest(String... indices) {
    this.indices = indices;
}
```

Comment: The same things as in Java, C++ and C# I imagine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is called [varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html). It works for any type as long as it's the *last* argument in the signature.

Basically, any number of parameters are put into an array. This does not mean that it is equivalent to an array.

A method that looks like:

```
void foo(int bar, Socket baz...)
```

will have an *array* of Socket (in this example) called baz.

So, if we call `foo(32, sSock.accept(), new Socket())` we'll find an array with two Socket objects.

Calling it as `foo(32, mySocketArray)` will **not** work as the type is *not* configured to take an array. However, if the signature is a varargs of arrays you can pass one or more arrays and get a two-dimensional array. For example, `void bar(int bar, PrintStream[] baz...)` can take multiple arrays of PrintStream and stick them into a single `PrintStream[][]`.

Oddly enough, due to the fact that arrays are objects, `Object... foo` can take any number of arrays.

Comment: If you have an array you can use the spread operator: `foo(32, *mySocketArray)` will work. Works for Lists too.